# How can I sync a directory with Google Drive, using GNOME accounts?

Tags: gnome, google-drive

I can mount my Google Drive using GNOME, but can I set up something to sync a local directory to the remote directory? I noticed that the filesystem is mounted at something like `/run/user/gvfs...`, but all the directory names are just random numbers and letters.

Can I use rsync maybe? Or something else?