# Can you navigate GNOME Google Drive with terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome, pop-os, google-drive

I'm setting up my new System76 machine with Pop!_OS, which allowed me to login with Google Drive with GNOME, however (as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526320/how-can-i-sync-a-directory-with-google-drive-using-gnome-accounts)), if you navigate through the GUI file browser to terminal, they're all nonsense directories.

```
me@computer:/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=umn.edu,user=day00096/0AFek83kcetSAUk9PVA/12ufV37RpRjKS_9nESfx-_TZu-URS60Wg$ ls
ls: cannot read symbolic link '1X_NxYmqWHWK9-_aYs2kwB2gTUCi1UTQrBFxjnYot_l8': Function not implemented
1de7iFQbh9IZHkvIl_yffExW2p9HzEqt1  1Qy36sTw5-GR0v8N6blJ-DT3bvTF_WjS9
1FWFxl-bk6I3ltkHNU6D3FyI3gIn-bgRq  1Qzkou7NFgd9uz2z4JwTg0Mywx8kkGiKG
1_OI3GF5L5g2sgMA3mG-KERyMRwJFnZ84  1X_NxYmqWHWK9-_aYs2kwB2gTUCi1UTQrBFxjnYot_l8
1pBdONvNmylanP1sqJcGem4TzsIb3LEKk
```

Is there a way to navigate this like a regular directory tree? I'm aware of the other options but have never had good luck setting them up on other computers.

Answer (score 4):

As found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264919/176850), you can think of `gio list -d` as an `ls` equivalent for Drive (i.e. `gio list google-drive://user@gmail.com`) See also `gio copy` & `gio open`.

These will allow you to at least browse your files from terminal, but I'm still searching for a way to simulate a local filesystem so I can add mine as a media source.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to browse from a terminal, I'm trying to set the working directory in differentt languages.